# Add values from DB (Select Query) in a text. Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql

On my Homepage i made i **Visual Studio** i want to have some welcome text on my firstpage.

The Thing is  that i want in the middle of the text present some values that i grab from my db with a select query.

Lets say for example:

Welcome to my Homepage!

Currently there are `(Select Count(UserID) FROM users where Status = 'active')` Users active on my page and `(Select Count(UserID) FROM users where Status = 'inactive')` that are inactive.

Im really new to this but somehow i Need to run the my questions on Page_load and then be able to take that value and present it in a Label or something?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Using ADO.NET:

1: Create a `connection` object, set it's `connection string` property

2: Create a `command` object and set its `text` property to

```
Select Count(UserID) FROM users where Status = 'active'
```

3: Use `ExecuteScalar` method of the command object to find the result you want and set the label `text` property equal to that result.

Answer (score 0):

**Procedure**

```
create procedure select
@activity
as
Begin
 Select Count(UserID) FROM users where Status = @activity
end
```

**C# Page Load**

```
string activity1="active";
string activity2="Inactive";
sqlconnection con=new sqlconnection("give your connection string");
sqlcommand cmd=new sqlcommand();
cmd=new sqlcommand("select",con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@activity",activity1);
String result1=cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

sqlcommand cmd1=new sqlcommand();
cmd1=new sqlcommand("select",con);
cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@activity",activity2);
String result2=cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Label1.Text=result1;
Label2.Text=result2;
```

**.aspx page**

Welcome to my  HomePage
Currently there are `<asp:label id="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>` Users active on my page and `<asp:label id="Label2" runat="server"></asp:Label>` that are inactive.
If you find this as useful and it solved your issue mark it as answer and give upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"MY CONNECTION");
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Select Count(UserID) FROM users where Status = 'active'", con);
        SqlDataReader dr;
        con.Open();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(dr[0].ToString());
        }
        con.Close();
    }
```